# Is this correct way of including Quickblox SDK into to my existing android project?

Tags: android, quickblox, instant-messaging, quickblox-android

I want to embed chat feature in my already existing Android App. It already includes Login Credentials.
 So, I tried to add the Quickblox SDK into my existing android project which was downloaded from GitHub Link [GitHub](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases)

**Also, Is Q-municate Android Source code which is published in GitHub [link](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android) also needs to be added in my existing app or not ?**

Or Without that Q-municate Source code, Can I develop chat feature Only by importing Quickblox SDK in My Existing App ?

**This is my project's top level build.gradle file**

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    def qbSdkVersion = '3.2.0'
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.1.0'
        compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:$qbSdkVersion"
        //include only necessary module dependency, all transitive modules will be included automatically

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
           url = "file://C:/Users/HP/Downloads/quickblox-android-sdk-releases-master"
            // url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This is module level build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sensei.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
greendao {
    schemaVersion 1
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.1.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:$qbSdkVersion" //include only necessary module dependency, all transitive modules will be included automatically
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:$qbSdkVersion"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:$qbSdkVersion"
    сompile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:$qbSdkVersion"

    debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
    debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link for simple chat functionality integration with QuickBlox

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat

You need to add the code in your project for chat functionality like one to one chat or group chat and all from the above example.

Comment: I observed the sample-chat has the dependency of sample-core .